# Use vc100 platform toolset without installing Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

A while ago I was able to install the vc90 platform toolset via Windows SDK v6.0a and use it in my Visual Studio 2013.

I now need to use the vc100 toolset and cannot find where it is integrated? Is there a way to use the vc100 toolset without installing Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: My guess would be that it's in the Windows SDK v7, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The vc100 toolset is part of SDK v7.0a.

Comment: The Wikipedia page says that this version of Windows SDK is just usable with VS2010 Prof installed. I hoped to install vc100 from anywhere without using a full vs2010 license. Hope it's not the only way to get it :/

Comment: If you have SDK v7.0a then you have the 2010 toolset. That's how I do it. Getting hold of old SDKs is the tricky bit.

Comment: But you can just install the SDK 7.0a with VS2010 being installed.

Comment: Indeed you can. If you can get hold of that version of the SDK.

Comment: @MOnsDaR what about VS2010 Ultimate? I have installed VS2010 Ultımate but cannot see VC100 in platform toolsets. There are only V100 and V90

Comment: @Hilal That's just a naming confusion. vc90 and v90 are the exact same thing.